# File Upload with Partial View MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to upload a number and a file through an Html-Helper form in my MVC 5 application. After submitting the model, it seems that my `model.File` property from the view model always returns `null`.

Before adding the `model.File != null` check, my application was throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

I have my form logic contained in a partial view called `UploadFile.cshtml`, since my form logic requires a different model than my `index.cshtml`.

How do I read the `File` property from my form in my `[HttpPost]` controller action?

index.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("UploadFile", "Home")
```

UploadFile.cshtml

```
@model FileViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("FormUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Marker)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

HomeController

```
    public PartialViewResult UploadFile()
    {
        return PartialView("UploadFile", new FileViewModel());
    }

    // /Home/FormUpload
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FormUpload(FileViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0 && model.File.ContentType == "application/pdf")
            {
                // Convert file to byte[] and upload
                // ...
                ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "File Not Uploaded";
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

FileViewModel

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Marker { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing enctype attribute for the form, you need to specify that for file case:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormUpload", "Home", 
                       FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

See [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) for further details.

Comment: Oh wow, what a simple thing to miss. Thanks for the quick response! I'll mark it as answer when SO lets me.

Comment: yes beginners mostly miss this and they can't figure out why file is coming null :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Html.BeginForm("FormUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

should be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```